# curl or file_get_contents ignore output

Tags: php, curl

I need to run a php code in a different server (let's call it server 2) from server 1.

In server 1, I have something like this

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://domain_in_server_2.com/php-script.php');
?>
```

The problem is, this request may take long time, and I don't need to get the output. I just want to trigger the script without having to wait or getting the output.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I want?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This depends significantly on `domain_in_server_2.com`'s configuration - PHP scripts [may quit if the client disconnects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

Comment: I think my question is clear enough, i'm not using a browser. My goal is to trigger the script and not to care how it work/output. Or how to "disconnect" as in your comment

Comment: `file_get_contents('http...')` will, for the purposes of `domain_in_server_2.com`, be like accessing via a browser. Your `file_get_contents` script may **have** to wait for output.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is just an example, I also included `curl` in the title.

Comment: **Doesn't matter.** `domain_in_server_2.com` has no idea if the request is coming from a browser or a CLI script. It looks the same to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a socket. See this [example](https://www.experts-exchange.com/viewCodeSnippet.jsp?codeSnippetId=20-38198193-1).

Edit:

Here is the code from the above link:

```
// Example:
// post_async("http://www.server.com/somewhere",array("foo" => 123, "bar" => "ABC"));

function post_async($url, $params)
{
    // Build POST string
    foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
      if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
      $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

    // Connect to server
    $parts=parse_url($url);
    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,$errno, $errstr, 30);

    // Build HTTP query             
    $out = "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    $out.= $post_string;

    // Send data and close the connection
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to see if it work and report it here

Comment: Hi @Joel, your method works, the script in server 1 does not wait, but from server 2 how to extract the post data. `file_put_contents('file.txt',$_POST["foo"])` creates an empty `file.txt` file. Thank you very much

Comment: Anyway, I don't really need the post data, just to make the question more useful. I have accepted the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Joel, please edit your answer and add some more useful information (maybe extracts from your link). Links may become obsolete (web goes down, article gets modified, etc) and this answers loses its value then.

Comment: There is a mistake in that example that prevent post data from being capture. `$type` should be replaced with `POST`. Then it works fine. Thanks!